# Selection dropdown in Ruby on Rails: selected value not being picked up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got this problem where I get the dropdown showing but the selected option is not showing up. Here's the code I have to generate the selection dropdown in the .erb:

```
<%= collection_select("url", "source_type_id", @source_types, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Please select..."}) %>
```

The `@source_types` is populated in the controller from a lookup table that is tied to the model. `@url_object` is the model:

```
@source_types = SourceType.all
```

Because of the way the model is tied to the lookup table:

```
belongs_to :source_type
```

`@url_object.source_type_id` returns the numeric value, and `@url_object.source_type` returns the associated name from the lookup table.

```
<select id="url_source_type_id" name="url[source_type_id]"><option value="">Please   select...</option>
<option value="1">Dictionary/Thesaurus</option>
<option value="2">Encyclopedia</option>
<option value="3">Magazine</option>
<option value="4">Map/Atlas</option>
<option value="5">Newspaper</option>
<option value="6">Reference Tools</option></select>
```

I read the API for this method and the implication is that if the `source_type_id` is present the `collection_select` will automagically pick it up and set the selected value, but this is clearly not happening.

I'm hoping someone will see what obvious mistake I've made here...

Comment: What does "not showing up" mean?  In the view or when you save it?  What does your form look like?

Comment: ah, I meant that the option was not showing as selected...the default one always shows. And it turns out I was forgetting (didn't know about) an option for the method call to set :selected => someint.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help
<%= f.select :source_type_id, @source_types.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id] }, params[:source_type_id] %>

Comment: I think this is a good solution as well. automates the marking of selected.